# JavaScript, function's argument is not working on loop

Tags: javascript, function, loops, arguments, indentation

I want a function that takes the name of the row in the JSON file and returns a list of elements from that row based on that argument... if "DRIVER" is called then I should get all the drivers in that row, if "COMPANY" is called, then all the companies...I've done several attempts to get it, like concatinating +".argument" but it does not seem to work.
Any help will be greatly appreciated..

```
const data = require('./drivers.json'); // THIS IS MY FILE 

function getInfo(argument){
    console.log(argument);
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i+=1) {
        console.log(data1[i].argument);       //UNDEFINED 
    }

}

getInfo('DRIVER');
```

Comment: It depends on what the JSON looks like, but you can try `console.log(data1[i][argument]);`

Comment: It's important to show your json structure

Answer (score 0):

If you have an object `obj = {hello: 'World')`, and a variable `var = 'hello'`, access it like this `obj[var]`.

Your current implementation will retrieve `obj['argument']`, which is not defined.

Answer (score -1):

There is a mistake in your code. You are using `data` as input to the for loop, but in the loop you use `data1`. This should fix it:

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i+=1) {
    console.log(data[i].argument);       
}
```

There is no way your code will ever work with your typo in it.